# How much can I expect my vocal range to improve with high quality vocal training

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I am a 22 year old male. My range is currently E2 to G#4 and I am untrained.

How do I fare compared to your "average joe" singer in terms of the size of my range? I understand that there are plenty of different vocal ranges, I believe I am a Baritone, however I'm not really sure.

With 6 months or so of vocal training by a good coach, can I expect my range to improve much? Even by a couple of semitones?

Comment: You need to ask yourself, How far are you willing to take the sessions and how determined are you to learn. any teacher can teach you (albeit if they are qualified or competent enough to do so) but you need to be willing to learn. If you self trained you may find it hard to be taught. Just an initial impression I'm providing here. No assumptions.

Comment: Update: I have been receiving vocal lessons for a year and can now sing up to A# on a good day in full chest-voice, with 2 30 minute lessons a week and a bit of practice.

I have a twin brother who is also getting lessons, and has found his "Mixed" voice and can now sing up to a tenor C in a full and rich chesty sounding voice

Comment: Another Update for anyone interested, I have found my Mixed Voice and can now comfortable hit a High C in a chesty sounding mix on a good day

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a pretty big range already.  You may have a few more high notes available (or ways of integrating your falsetto range, appropriate to some styles of singing).  "Baritone" is about quality of voice as well as range.  Do you see entension of range as the primary purpose of taking singing lessons?

If you want to be a tenor, go to a teacher (or a few teachers) and see if they think it's possible.  Try to focus on what you *could* do rather than where they feel your voice sounds best (but also take that information on board).

'You can do anything if you try hard enough' may be good advice if you want to be President.  But it's often just blather.  I want to be a soprano.  I'm a 68 year old man with genitals intact.  It ain't going to happen!

Comment: Basically yes, the style of music I want to sing basically requires the tenor range, so if I can improve the quality and my endurance at the higher end of my range, and gain a bit more of the high end, that is what I want to achieve

Comment: OK, go to a teacher and see if they think YOU can be turned into a tenor. Don't be too disappointed if the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure we can tell. The maximum vocal range is partly determined by genetics. And though 2 octaves is pretty impressive it still doesn't tell us how much more there is to explore in your voice. One possibility is that you're still far from your boundaries. In this case a professional teacher can help you radically increase your range in a few years. Then again it's also possible is that 2 octaves is all there is for you and you have been naturally talented enough to be able to use it for yourself without doing much harm. In this case a teacher may be able to give you a few semitones more, but if you're already on your boundaries those few semitones may also cost you years of training.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is like "what height can I expect to clear when getting professional sports training?  I currently jump over boulders of height $x." in more than one respect.

First, in the fixation on range as a single factor.  Professional singing is not primarily a frequency competition: the problem is not making high/low-pitched noises, but rather sounds that people will actually enjoy hearing, and doing so reliably and repeatedly.

Second, there is absolutely no way to predict what kind of "pitch potential" you are already exploiting and what not, and where your overall potential would be.

The way to find out is to take up training under supervision of somebody who actually knows what he or she is doing.

Like with general sports/fitness, there is a lot one can do on one's own just to get into generally good shape, and like with general sports/fitness this tends to be a rather benign manner of getting into shape up to the moment where one get ambitious and aiming for some kind of personal achievements instead of just doing things while they feel good.

Like angling for highest pitch.  That can become a rather destructive endeavor if obsessed with it, particularly without supervision.

Comment: Truly a politicians answer. You don't have to answer if you are not able to give me something quantitative

Answer (score 1):

I am a self taught singer with a current range of F#2 to C5. I used to have a range of about F#2 to G4 and thought I was a baritone to begin with. I extended my higher notes up to C5 by following the exercises given in this video

(There is part 1 and part 2 make sure you do both). I also did some lip trills along the piano scale as a warmup before doing the 2 exercises in the 2 part video. It is given to not strain when doing the exercises, a little tension is fine but do not strain.

Answer (score 0):

I mean I have a pretty similar range from Eb2 - G#4 But my full voice range is C2 - Bb4. It seems as though the more I sing the higher I go because at first I was stuck at E2 - B3 or C4 but as I started to sing more it increased to E2 - E4 and now Eb2 - G#4. I am untrained as well but I’m gonna take lessons for the next few years and see how that goes

Answer (score 0):

I believe singing is all about mindset and physical training. First, you have to define your vocal range where you are at. Second, where do you want to go about your vocal range. Third, once you are able to hit your target notes, it’s all about how you project them in the artistic ways, e.g. in terms of full voice,  falsetto, etc. To just hit those notes is insufficient but as a singer, you have to convey those notes in a beautiful way to communicate them to listeners.

However, with physical training and your mindset, you can even expand your vocal range to whistle register (I personally do not believe in physical limitation). But you have to understand your voice and body in order to make the best out of it. As a result, you can increase your vocal range to your full potential. One thing that is hard for learning singing is that a teacher or a professional singer cannot show you how his/her diaphragm work inside while singing. But they can only tell you how they feel the sensation. Therefore, you have to use your visualization more to adjust your body to sing it properly. Once you nail it, you know it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are "untrained" it is questionable that this is really a singing range.  With no training some of the higher notes might not be sung with proper resonance or support!

It is always a good idea to take lessons.  Classical training would be good, you'll learn proper support and how to aim notes internally and you will get feedback on issues as they arise.

I can offer personal experience.  I been taking classical voice lessons for 1.5 years and my range increased significantly as I learned to sing properly.  I am a bass/tenor, can hit about a 4th above high C.  However there are physical limits to range.  The only way to know what your limits are is to keep trying.  I'd recommend lessons and see how that helps.  You may have found your limit or it may increase.  Even if you don't get more range from lessons you will learn to be a better singer, learn how to get good tone, take care of your voice, etc.